# How many timers (timerfds) can I safely open and use in linux?

Tags: linux, timer

In my application I use linux timers created with `timerfd_create`.

Then I listen for events on all of those timers using `epoll` mechanism.

How many of them can I safely create? 10? 100? 1,000? 1,000,000? I assume no operating system "soft" limit, this is more about OS and hardware possibilities.

If most of timers are operating on the same frequency, should I consider replacing them with single timer + iterating over their targets?

Comment: 1024 should be the usual limit for file descriptors, per process.